# How do I setup a ASP.net Core MVC web application to IIS when publishing it creates .dll, .pdb, and .json files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to setup the default ASP.net Core MVC Web application on my local IIS. I publish it using a folder profile, but it generates .dll, .pdb, and .json files. Before, publishing it on the Webforms would generate .aspx and .ashx files I could drag and move to the folder for my web application. I've done some googling but I haven't been able to find a solution or tutorial on what to do with these files. So I'm kinda lost and in need of assistance.

FYI I'm on VS2019 and my project uses the ASP.net Core 2.1 framework. I'm also running IIS version 10.0.19041.1.

EDIT: clarified that it should be IIS, not IIS Express.
EDIT: changed my comparison to WebForms to what it actually creates. Some reason I thought it does .html.

Comment: "IIS" or "IIS Express"? They are not the same thing so you have to edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Web Forms did *not* generate .html files that you would move to the folder for your application. Not sure where you got that misconception.

Comment: @LexLi I believe its IIS now. I opened the IIS manager and checked the "About IIS Manager" window and it lists "Internet Information Services(Version 10.0.190.41.1)". I will make corresponding edits in the question.

Comment: @mason Ok, double-checking my bad. Publishing on webforms generates .aspx and .ashx files. I will make corresponding edits.

Comment: @KurtisHonk-KurtChow Sure, and Web Forms can include.dll, .pdb and .json files. What Web Forms does is not relevant to your question, so you really shouldn't even mention it. There's also no need to leave an edit summary at the bottom of your question. There's a built in edit history functionality.

Comment: You need to watch some tutorials before asking this question.

Comment: @KurtisHonk-KurtChow if the question is closed and the answer satisfy you please accept it as answered Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi yep it's not straight forward I had a bit off difficulty the first time.

You first have to install the support for IIS from here.
[Download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
But know that 2.1 is not supported any longer I think.

1 IIS > add sites
2 create your site in the inetpub folder with whatever name you like.

3 paste the content of this folder in the app. C:\Users\yourUser\source\repos\projectName\projectname\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish

4 It is an app so the .dll etc is exactly what you need. Check the doc it explains how to install the support off .net core it is not native of IIS

[Official Doc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLUZdQBzn54&list=PLxZTKHeLjTSBj4jQwiKflcTrIrF5uYIVH&index=16)
Microsoft official documentation on How to deploy the website.

[youtube video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Follow carefully the Doc and it should be Ok